# how connect wirelessly a device without wifi adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, router, repeater

I want connect my PC which is in another room. I use a repeater with Ethernet port but I cant disable the wifi repeating. I won't connect wifi adapter to my PC. I can't find another way to do this ??

Comment: I’ve read your question three times now and still don’t understand what you’re asking. I appreciate English might not be your first language but can you try to make it clearer? Put it in Google Translate if you must.

Answer (score -1):

You can also connect to your PC using Bluetooth or USB tethering

Enable Bluetooth in Computer and pair it to your android device, then goto **Setting>More>Tethering and Portable hotspot>** enable Bluetooth Tethering. or USB tethering

Answer (score -1):

1. Power down repeater
2. Run Ethernet cable from pc nic to repeater port
3. Power down pc
4. Power up repeater
5. Power up pc
6. Press wps button on isp modem
7. Press button on repeater

or open a browser on a pc and complete the registration and route linkage.